# 'I feel like bread baked in an oven.' is this sentence correct?

Tags: tense, past-participles, present-participles

I am in a very hot room, or I was in a very hot room, so I got scalded. In this case:

a. I feel like bread **baking** in an oven.
b. I feel like bread **baked** in an oven.

Are both of these sentence correct ? Expecially 'b' is possible in grammar?

Someone(we are non native, so not sure 'b' is correct or not) says 'bake is intransitive verb in this sentence, so 'b' is impossible in grammar. So, is 'baked' impossible in any context or any case? and not natural?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you feel overheated? Or that you have a desire to eat fresh-baked bread?

Comment: @TRomano for example, I am very hot in this room, so  feel overheated

Comment: Who told that [bake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bake) is only intransitive? It's also transitive. 1. **I am baking** (cooking food in an oven) 2. **I bake bread**. Both are correct. In any case, the verb in your sentence is "feel": (I feel like) I am as hot as bread baked fresh from the oven = I feel like hot (baked) bread.

Comment: Both of your descriptive sentences, in which you compare yourself to a loaf of bread in the oven, are grammatical. But there is a short idiomatic phrase, "I'm baking!" which means "I am feeling very overheated, it's so hot here." It often begins with the exclamation "Phew!" (pronounced "few" but with a bit of a whistle).  "Phew! I'm baking".

Answer (score 2):

I would say to use the first sentence:

> It's hot in here! I feel like bread baking in an oven.

Even the next day, when you change the verb *feel* to its past tense form, I'd still use the first sentence:

> It was hot in there! I felt like bread baking in an oven.

In this instance, I don't like using the past tense *baked* because that implies the bread is out of the oven and is already cooling off. I think it detracts from your metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, but some purists would say that b. needs a comma:

```
a. I feel like bread baking in an oven.
b. I feel like bread, baked in an oven.
```

Between the two, there's a slight difference:

a. Is present tense (really hot, and under pressure!)
b. Is past tense (still hot, but limp from the process!)

Comment: If I don't use a comma, is b wrong ?

Comment: @redkey88 Wrong? No. There are different ideas on that. I gave the traditional version, but I agree that the version without the comma is acceptable. The comma _emphasises_ that the sentence is in the past tense: the bread was definitely baked and has been removed from the oven. Without that, it could imply that the bread is still in the oven, fully baked

Comment: oh, sorry, You misunderstood my question. my explanation was insufficient. sorry. this is not real bread. for example I was in very hot room, so, I feel like I'm bread in oven.

Comment: @redkey88 Ah, but that's the thing about a "metaphor". If you're going to 'pretend' that you're bread in an oven,, then you need to use all the English syntax to "be" bread in an oven. So, my comment stands.